# Reading certain lines of a string

Tags: python, list, printing, lines

Hi I am trying to read a csv file into a double list which is not the problem atm.

What I am trying to do is just print all the sL values between two lines. I.e i want to print sL [200] to sl [300] but i dont want to manually have to type print sL for all values between these two numbers is there a code that can be written to print all values between these two lines that would be the same as typing sL out individually all the way from 200 to 300

Comment: Welcome to SO! In what language are trying to do that? What have you tried?

Comment: Trying to do it in python language so far i have only manually typed print sL [200], print sL[201] etc to 300 so i dont know if it is possible to print all these without typing it manually

Comment: wait, actually, to clarify: you're operating on the file content after it's slurped into a list of the lines?

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n 200,300p`, perhaps, for 200 to 300 inclusive; adjust the numbers by ±1 if exclusive or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in sl[200:301]:
    print line
```

Python ranges function are inclusive on the left side and exclusive on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a specific column ranging between 200 and 300, use `filter()` function.

`new_array = filter(lambda x: x['column'] >= 200 or z['column'] <= 300, sl)`